# How to open keyboard into service on Android

Tags: java, android, service

In my application i should use **`Vertical Stepper`** and for this i added below **library** : [VerticalStepperForm](https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm).
I should use this stepper into `service` and for this i write below codes.
But when use this codes into `Service`, when click on `EditText` n**ot open soft keyboard** (not show me any keyboard), but when use this codes into `activity`, it's not bug and **show me keyboard**.
But into `service` **not show any keyboard**!

**My service codes:**

```
public class FloatingLayoutService extends Service implements StepperFormListener {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ConstraintLayout floatingLayout, floatingLay_root, floatingLay_main;
    private IBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();
    private LinearLayout floatingLay_headerLay;
    private List<Step> steps = new ArrayList();
    private List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TestStepsListResponse.Datum> testPlans = new ArrayList<>();
    //Timer
    private boolean running;
    private int stepIndex = 1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the layout using LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        floatingLayout = (ConstraintLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_layout, null);
        //Init view
        initUi();
        //Set layout params to display the controls over any screen.
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        // From API26, TYPE_PHONE deprecated. Use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY for O
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        //Initial position of the floating controls
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        //Add the controls view to windowManager
        windowManager.addView(floatingLayout, params);
        //Steps
        testPlans = App.testPlansList;
        for (int i = 0; i < testPlans.size(); i++) {
            if (testPlans.get(i).getItemType().equals(ConstKeys.TEST_STEP_TEXT_RESPONSE)) {
                StepDynamicEdt stepDynamicTxt = new StepDynamicEdt(testPlans.get(i).getTitle(), testPlans.get(i).getDesc());
                // add to list
                steps.add(stepDynamicTxt);
                intList.add(i);
            } else {
                StepDynamicTxt stepDynamicEdt = new StepDynamicTxt(testPlans.get(i).getTitle(), testPlans.get(i).getDesc());
                // add to list
                steps.add(stepDynamicEdt);
            }
        }

        floatingLay_stepper.setup(this, steps)
                .allowNonLinearNavigation(false)
                .displayCancelButtonInLastStep(false)
                .displayBottomNavigation(false)
                .confirmationStepTitle("OK")
                .stepNextButtonText("Next")
                .lastStepNextButtonText("Finish")
                .includeConfirmationStep(false)
                .init();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

**StepDynamicEdt class codes:**

```
public class StepDynamicEdt extends Step<String> {

    private static final int MIN_CHARACTERS = 1;
    private EditText editText;
    private String errorMessage;

    public StepDynamicEdt(String title) {
        this(title, "");
    }

    public StepDynamicEdt(String title, String subtitle) {
        super(title, subtitle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected View createStepContentLayout() {
        //Create view programmatically
        editText = new EditText(getContext());
        editText.setHint("User name");
        editText.setSingleLine(true);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                markAsCompletedOrUncompleted(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                getFormView().goToNextStep(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        errorMessage = "Insert 1 character";

        return editText;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStepData() {
        Editable text = editText.getText();
        if (text != null) {
            return text.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getStepDataAsHumanReadableString() {
        String name = getStepData();
        return name == null || name.isEmpty() ? "Empty" : name;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreStepData(String data) {
        if (editText != null) {
            editText.setText(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected IsDataValid isStepDataValid(String stepData) {
        if (stepData.length() < MIN_CHARACTERS) {
            return new IsDataValid(false, errorMessage);
        } else {
            return new IsDataValid(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepOpened(boolean animated) {
        // No need to do anything here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepClosed(boolean animated) {
        // No need to do anything here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepMarkedAsCompleted(boolean animated) {
        // No need to do anything here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepMarkedAsUncompleted(boolean animated) {
        // No need to do anything here
    }

}
```

**Update :** I added below code into `StepDynamicEdt` class, but again not open keyboard!

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
Objects.requireNonNull(imm).showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

How can i fix it and open keyboard into `service` ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just putting that in an `Activity`? I mean, it's fullscreen, right?

Comment: @MikeM. , i should show this VerticalStepper in overlay other app. for this i should use service!

Comment: @MikeM., can you help me my friend?

Comment: "for this i should use service!" – Hmm, not necessarily. Anyway, it's `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` that's preventing that. You can pass `0` there for no flags. Be careful with this, though. From experience, if something goes wrong, it's easy to get stuck with a focusable window on top that interferes with everything, to the point where you almost have to reboot to get rid of it.

Comment: @MikeM. , thanks but can you send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur and i really need your help i want see code for understand this. can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: There is no new code, really. Just replace `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` with `0`.

Comment: @MikeM., yes yes your answer help me. thaaaaaaaanks my dear friend. can you send your answer in another post for accept it and perhaps help to other developers?

Comment: No problem. This is a rather common question, though, and it's been answered here several times already, so I'll just close this as a duplicate. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!